# Mysql authentication

Tags: mysql, wamp, sha256

I am having trouble getting my database to connect in wamp. It's been about 5 years since i've done this so i'm a little rusty. I upgraded my Mysql to 8.0 and I came across the error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [sha256_password] in C:\wamp64\www\dirtyosrs\assets\lib\core\Database.class.php:34 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\dirtyosrs\assets\lib\core\Database.class.php(34): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', NULL, NULL, Array) #1 C:\wamp64\www\dirtyosrs\assets\lib\init.php(34): Database->connect() #2 C:\wamp64\www\dirtyosrs\templates\header.php(8): require_once('C:\\wamp64\\www\\d...') #3 C:\wamp64\www\dirtyosrs\index.php(1): include('C:\\wamp64\\www\\d...') #4 {main} Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in C:\wamp64\www\dirtyosrs\assets\lib\core\Database.class.php on line 34

PDOException: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [sha256_password] in C:\wamp64\www\dirtyosrs\assets\lib\core\Database.class.php on line 34
```

I flushed my privileges and changed the plugin to native on root. i'm stumped at this point. could someone help me?

here is my database class up to line 37

```
<?php
```

/**

- Class Database
  */
  class Database {

  private $IP, $username, $password, $database;

  /**

  - @var PDO
    */
    private $connection;
    private $query = 0;

  /**

  - Database constructor.
  - @param $IP
  - @param $username
  - @param $password
  - @param $database
    */
    public function __construct($IP, $username, $password, $database) {
    $this->IP = $IP;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->database = $database;
    }

  /**

  - Attempts to connect to the host
    */
    public function connect() {
    $this->connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->IP.';dbname='.$this->database.';charset=utf8', $this->username, $this->password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql 8 has since 2018 a new default type of secure authentication method (sha2) that can be hard to get to work on localhost. In order to continue to use the traditional auth method, I do it like this in my Dockerfile:

`command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`

If you set up manually you have to run the default-authentication command on your database setup.

More info here: https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-default-authentication-plugin-considerations/

Comment: I never restarted my wamp after making the changes before making this. it's solved now. This would have worked for me had I not already done it. So thank you very much!